# F# error FS0039: The type 'XmlProvider' is not defined

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-interactive, f#-data, fslab

Looked at these for a couple solutions--but nothing works
[The type 'XmlProvider' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625514/the-type-xmlprovider-is-not-defined) 
[F# Data New type provider library](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-data.aspx/)
[F# Data: XML Type Provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html)

```
open FSharp.Data
type XMLcountries = XmlProvider<"http://api.worldbank.org/country">
let sampleCountries = XMLcountries.GetSample()
let sampleCountries' = XMLcountries.Load("http://api.worldbank.org/country")
```

When using the interactive window, I get F# error FS0039: The type 'XmlProvider' is not defined. 
Is there a better package/library to use XML provider(and JSON too).

I have updated FSharp.Data to version 2.3.1

I added open FSharp.Data.TypeProviders to see if that would work. Still same error.

This is extremely frustrating.

Comment: "*When using the interactive window*" is the key – FSI needs to reference the assembly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [F#, namespaces, modules, fs and fsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354984/f-namespaces-modules-fs-and-fsx)

Comment: do you have FSLab (http://fslab.org/) installed? then you could say `#load @"..\..\FSLAB\packages\FSLAB\FsLab.fsx"` and your life would be much easier. Otherwise reference the dll with `#r` or just right click on the Reference and send to F# Interactive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you have looked at [F# Data: XML Type Provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html/)? Because at the very beginning it says:

```
#r "../../../bin/FSharp.Data.dll"
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"
open FSharp.Data
```

So you have a couple of options, if you don't want to install FSlab, the second one is the easiest for you. You obviously have to adjust the path to match your environment.

1. Download and install [FSLab](http://fslab.org/download/), then reference FSLab with
   `#load @"..\..\FSLAB\packages\FSLAB\FsLab.fsx"`
2. Reference FSharp.Data.dll in your script:
   `#r @"..\..\FSLAB\packages\FSharp.Data\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"`
3. Add FSharp.Data to your References in Visual Studio and send the reference to FSI with a rigt-click (I do hope you have installed [the Visual F# Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/136b942e-9f2c-4c0b-8bac-86d774189cff/)).

[image: the Visual F# Power Tools]

Comment: red squiggly lines for #r "../../../bin/FSharp.Data.dll"
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll" FSLAB and Powertools installed

Comment: well, you have to specify the actual path to FSharp.Data.dll... or Just add the Dlls to the references in VS then do Send to F# Interactive. then you won't need to #r it.

Comment: I have sent it to the interactive every package to the interactive and i have put the #r about the open section

Comment: its usually good to be specific about the error...can u join f# chat?

Comment: I get the same F# error FS0039: The type 'XmlProvider' is not defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115853/discussion-between-s952163-and-aaron-m).